# CSS selector (:scope > *) works on Windows but not Linux OS with headless puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automation, css-selectors, puppeteer

I am working on an automation project with Puppeteer, and I am using the CSS selector (:scope > *) to select all the child elements of an element, and when I test this on my local development machine (CS Code + Windows 10) running headless puppeteer, everything works very fine. As soon as I deploy it to an EC2 running Linux, I start getting error messages where the selector cannot find the element.

I have extracted the HTML element and compared to what I have local, and they are the same - No differences. The Chromium versions are the same on both machines. I have tried setting the window size to maximum but everything has failed and I have no more ideas on why this selector is failing on the Linux machine. Any ideas or clues. Below is the code I am using to select.

```
 let c1Node = await spList.$$(':scope > *');
 let studentId= await this.#page.evaluate((el) => el.getAttribute('data-student-id'), c1Node[0]);
```

I consistently get this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute').

Comment: You're probably beiing detected as a bot and blocked.

Comment: @ggorlen That's a very interesting idea, I didnt think of that. How would that be possible when the element clearly exists in the DOM, the code just cannot read the values?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting the server detects your script as a bot and blocks it, serving a different DOM where the element isn't present. To debug, `console.log(await page.content())` and see if it contains what you expect it to. If you're blocked, you may see a message to the effect of "blocked by cloudflare". I also notice you're not using `waitForSelector`, so that's another important step to try. If you are blocked, try adding a user-agent header. This is all speculation since we don't have a [mcve] here so there's no way to say for sure what might be going on.

Comment: Also possible: whatever site you're scraping serves different pages to clients in different regions and your server is getting a different layout or A/B testing type situation.

Comment: I examined the DOM and HTML and it is exactly what I have when I run on windows. No differences which is all the more confusing.

Comment: Hmm, weird. I'd go with `waitForSelector` then. It could also have to do with visibility.